# Type error 'int' is not callable in a for in range loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, integer

the prob is in line

```
for a in range ( n , -1 , -1 ):
```

I dont know why tried every possible solution I can think of. Tried even to change n -> 0+n or 1*n.
But its always the Type Error 'int' is not callable.

```
n = 1
number = int(text_int)
range = len(dict002)
coefficent=[]
while (number/(36**n))>36 and (number/(36**n))<1:
    n += 1
for a in range ( n , -1 , -1 ):
    coefficent.append(number//(range**i))
    number= (number/(range**i))-(number//(range**i))
print(coefficent)
```

Comment: You redefined `range` when you did `range = len(dict002)`. Don't use built-in function names as variables.